# Tomcat manager with virtual hosts

Tags: java, tomcat, hosts

I have three web services running under three different domains in Tomcat.  I have have four host entries in my server.xml:

1. localhost
2. Webservice1.com
3. Webservice2.com
4. Webservice3.com

Currently I can only access the Tomcat Web Application Manager on localhost.  How can I get the web application manager to run on the other three hosts.

Tariq

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your log files?

Also, make sure you have host entries for the three other servivces (i.e. in your hosts file).

What version of Tomcat are you using?

Lastly, have you checked here?

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html#Webapps_Directory